# How to use requestCode in PendingIntents

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm trying to implement a reminder app.I have all reminder details stored in sqlite database such id,title,dateInfo,timeInfo etc.

I want to notify the user at appropriate time about the reminder for which i would be using AlarmManager.

Is the below given steps feasible.

Providing id of row as requestCode in pendentingIntents.
Then setting an alarm that would call a service once triggered.
The service would use this id to get data from the database.

If this is feasible can anyone pls provide me with a code snippet.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put your rowId as extra in the called intent. Here's a code snippet that might help:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, YourServiceOrActivity.class);
i.putExtra("rowId", rowId);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 123123, i, 0); //Notice the random requestCode '123123' as it doesn't matter, yet.
```

And you can set the alarm as follows:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi); 
//Set the alarm to wake up the device after one day calling the pending intent 'pi'.
```

Finally you can get the rowId from the intent (onCreate() for example if intent is an Activity) when called as follows:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) rowId = extras.getInt("rowId", 0); //Be safe
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned I would put `rowId` as an extra, *BUT* do not be mistaken - as wroten in [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) doc, intents are distinct as below:

> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something that is different about them to associate them with different PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by Intent. filterEquals, or **different request code** integers supplied to getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int, Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or getService(Context, int, Intent, int).

So if you put your request with the same `id` for all intents for the same row, with different data, you can get lost with obsolete/repeated data issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs on [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29), the `requestCode` of the `getService(...)` method is not used. It's not clear to me what happens to it, so I wouldn't rely on it in any way.

Just pass the row ID as an extra in the Intent.

Comment: Can i pass rowId to the alaramManager which would then forward it to service ? @karakuri

Comment: Edited my post. Use an intent extra, it will avoid confusion and there's no chance that any weird behavior will ever occur if the system is using that value internally somehow.